# Google Sheets Shared - onopen not running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a basic sheet script that runs proper if I'm logged in. The sheet
is shared with edit permissions. When I try running the shared link the
script doesn't run, and I get "Timed out waiting for user response (line 3, file "Code")"

Here is my script.

```
//Create Menu
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Hello, world');
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: That error usually appears if you dont quit out of the alert after 5 minutes. Are you saying you don't see the alert appear at all? And this when you are in the sheet as anonymous? How are you viewing the sheet?

Comment: No alert shown at all. and anyone with link can view / edit. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1abJBb07ifB6qoDIAbb5pGPwu8n6RTQLpNyoVW4T1tAo/edit#gid=1386834576

Comment: Make sure you consult your error logs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#exception_logging

Comment: The error in the log is: You do not have permission to call alert. How do I add permission to the shared sheet?

Comment: Opened your spreadsheet; alert opened when the "Working" light went out; I could close the alert. Sounds like an issue with project binding and/or permissions. Check [your permissions](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions). FWIW, I suggest deleting the project, exit the spreadsheet, then re-open, and build a new project and script. I've had "glitches" with renamed projects &/or scripts with new features added after the initial authorisation. Sometimes it's just easier to copy the scripts, delete and recreate the project and paste scripts back. It's invariably successful.